# Why is a Youtube embedded video with custom start and end times set restarting after video playback is complete?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I put together the following link which is supposed to play only 8 seconds of the video and then stop.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/YjmWnwKxOls?start=47&end=55&showinfo=0&modestBranding=1

When I open the URL in Chrome and MS Edge, they both respond the same way. The video starts playing at the specified start time, plays until the end time, looks like it's done where it quickly shows related videos in the player and then just automatically starts playing from the beginning of the video.

Looking at the API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), I don't see anything wrong with my URL where the player should be behaving this way. Any suggestions?

Comment: To follow up, I actually tried this with a completely different video and had different results where the video started and stopped as I expected. But for whatever reason, the video I provided in the original post restarts by itself after playback has hit my end time.

Answer (score 1):

Look for what I did, may it can help you:
In my code there is a playlist with autostart( only works on desktop) and the musics are played in a random sequency, until the counter  reset.
**You need to save in your computer and open it in order to see the result**

```html
<div id="number" style="color: red; margin-left: 200px;">asdfsdf</div>
<div id="arr" style="color: red; margin-left: 200px;">asdfsdf</div>

<div id="player"></div>
    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      //iqtdtJq1I_Q?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&start=40&end=47&playsinline=0'
      //iqtdtJq1I_Q?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&start=40&end=47&
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          
          /*height: '390',
          width: '640',
          //videoId: 'iqtdtJq1I_Q?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&start=35&end=37&',
           videoId: '4Uz8gLA6wbQ',
           playerVars: { start: '35',end: '50','autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },*/
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': function (event) {
                switch (event.data) {
                    case -1:
                        console.log ('unstarted');
                        
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        console.log ('ended');
                        getRandomWithManyExclusions()
                        event.target.cueVideoById({
                          videoId: videoName,
                          startSeconds: videoStart,
                          endSeconds: videoEnd
                        });
                        event.target.playVideo();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        console.log ('playing');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        console.log ('paused');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        console.log ('buffering');
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        console.log ('video cued');
                        break;
                }
            }
          }
        });
      }
      //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        getRandomWithManyExclusions();
        event.target.cueVideoById({
          videoId: videoName,
          startSeconds: videoStart,
          endSeconds: videoEnd
        });
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
      function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
      }
      
  var arrayOfIndexesToExclude = new Array();
  var videoName = 'am1_JLFDFMw';
  var videoStart = '19';
  var videoEnd = '21';

  function getRandomWithManyExclusions(){
    var rand = null;
      
     do{
       rand = Math.round(Math.random() * ( 9)); //numero aleatorio até 9
       if(arrayOfIndexesToExclude.length >= 10){ //10 é o numero de aleatorios totais, incluindo-se 0 
        arrayOfIndexesToExclude.length = 0;       
       }
    }while(arrayOfIndexesToExclude.includes(rand));
   
   arrayOfIndexesToExclude.push(rand);  
      switch(rand) {
        case 0:
          videoName = '8B-sFGfA3lM'; //WHOAMI
          videoStart = '38';
          videoEnd = '156';      
          break;
        case 1:
          videoName = 'gg5RwFL4F_w';//noise-x
          videoStart = '68';
          videoEnd = '193';          
          break;
        case 2:
          videoName = 'VX56xOe86UM'; //Nightmare God
          videoStart = '0';
          videoEnd = '49';
          break;
        case 3:
          videoName = '2VbKY2miqXo'; //Bloodvault X
          videoStart = '0';
          videoEnd = '57';
          break;
        case 4:
          videoName = 'AiCfXlYx9HI'; //Fukkk Offf
          videoStart = '41';
          videoEnd = '93';
          break;
        case 5:
          videoName = 'k_ZESIw3K0c'; //Cyber Electro
          videoStart = '49';
          videoEnd = '131';
          break;
        case 6:
          videoName = 'kQ6wY_mGuzQ'; //Scum of Mankind
          videoStart = '13';
          videoEnd = '55';
          break;
        case 7:
          videoName = '4Uz8gLA6wbQ'; //Extreme Terror
          videoStart = '35';
          videoEnd = '95';
          break;              
        case 8:
          videoName = 'ZJxX-MIXtXo'; //Terror Of My speedcore 1
          videoStart = '0';
          videoEnd = '59';
          break;
        case 9:
          videoName = 'ZJxX-MIXtXo'; //Terror Of My speedcore 2
          videoStart = '113';
          videoEnd = '134';
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      
    
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = arrayOfIndexesToExclude;
    document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = arrayOfIndexesToExclude.length;
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
              <!--<audio id="musica" autoplay volume="1" loop  >
  <source src="msc/playlist.wav" type="audio/wav"></source>
</audio>
https://www.youtube.com/embed/a1oSXlU0ZUk?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1



 if (arrayOfIndexesToExclude.length < 9){
      }else{
      arrayOfIndexesToExclude = [];
      getRandomWithManyExclusions();
    }

    switch(rand) {
      case 0: /*extreme terror*/
          document.getElementById['playerId'].src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/4Uz8gLA6wbQ?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1&start=35&end=95";
          break;
                       
      default:
          code block
    }
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = arrayOfIndexesToExclude;
    arrayOfIndexesToExclude.push(rand);
    
<iframe id="playerId" style="opacity:0;" type="text/html" width="100%" height="%f" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iqtdtJq1I_Q?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1&start=0&end=47" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>



    -->
```